# Disable options/button in javasscript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code as below :

```
p.onRowSelectExtraListener = function(e)
{
    var that = e.data.that;

    that.actions.selectedRows = that.table.getSelectedRows();
    var selected = [];
    var disableoption = false;
    $('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
        selected.push($(this).attr('statusid'));
    });

    $.each(selected, function(index, value) {
        if (value == 27)
        {
            disableoption = true;
            return false;
        }
        console.log(disableoption);
       if(disableoption === true)
           {
           console.log("calling another function");
           //call p.getRowActions and disable the 3rd menu item/button.option.
           }
    });
};

p.getRowActions = function()
{
    var that = this;
    var addToGroupOptions = this.data.group.slice(0);
    console.log("in get row actions");
    if (this.canUnlock == 0)
        {
            console.log("In Super-IF loop");
        }

    addToGroupOptions.unshift({id: 'new', name: 'new group'});
                //TODO translate
                return [
                    {
                        option: {id: '4', name: 'add to group'},
                        options: addToGroupOptions,
                        type: 'ajax',
                        func: function(selectedRows, group)
                        {
                            that.onAddToGroup(selectedRows, group);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        option: {id: '2', name: 'change rights issue'},
                        type: 'ajax',
                        func: function(selectedRows, rights) {
                            that.onChangeRights(selectedRows, rights);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        option: {id: '1', name: 'change status'},
                        options: this.data.status,
                        type: 'ajax',
                        func: function(selectedRows, status) {
                            that.onChangeStatus(selectedRows, status);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        option: {id: '3', name: 'edit'},
                        type: 'ajax',
                        func: function(selectedRows, edit) {
                            that.onChangeEdit(selectedRows, edit);
                        }
                    }
                ];
};
```

Now out of these two functions, the second one is called/executed first when I load my page.
Hence I can see `console.log("in get row actions");` printed as well as the 4 options under `return[]` statement present as buttons in my application.

Now my requirement is :

To disable the 3rd option(the option with id:1 name:change status whenever `disableoption = true` will be set in the 1st function.

How is that possible ?

How can I access and remove the property defined in diffrent function ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

p.getRowActions returns an array, access the objects within the array and change the property of the object you want, once the object is modified you can reassemble the array with the new object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and then return this *corrected* array to the component that consumes its data to add the HTML objects to the DOM.

Another option is to **insert a callback function at the end of the function that receives the array returned from `p.getRowActions`** so you can edit the object in the DOM **after** it is created/rendered.

**UPDATE (pseudo-code to illustrate solution):**

```
function some_function_that_consumes_getRowActions_that_is_somewhere_else_that_I_dont_know() {
    var arrayOfHTMLOptions = p.getRowActions();

    //inserting options to DOM...

    var theOptionYouWant = document.getElementById('1');
    theOptionYouWant.disabled = true;
}
```

Another option (that might be more elegant depending on the potential upcoming use cases that could require a new change on this function) is to override the method of object "p" through inheritance and build your own `p.getRowActions` returning the options array you want, then you must update the function that receives this array so it can point to the new "p child object", by doing that you will have a more flexible way to keep changing `p.getRowActions`.

Here's some cool reading on Object Oriented Programming with Javascript:
http://marcelorjava.wordpress.com/2014/06/07/object-oriented-programming-with-java-and-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for that help @Marcelor .
I have understood what you mean to say theoretically .
Can you please provide the implementation code in my case as I am naive to Javascript.